# PHP Multidimensional Arrays not showing expected result

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**Unable to produce results as expected in multi dimensional arrays.**

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

```
$menu = array ('COL1' => array('1' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), '2', '3', '4'), 'COL2' => array('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'COL3' => array('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'COL4' => array('1', '2', '3', '4') );

foreach ($menu as $col => $value) {
    echo '<hr>'.$col;
    foreach ($value as $item => $subitem) {
        echo '<br>'.$item;
        foreach ($subitem as $childitem) {
            echo '<br>'.$childitem;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Desire Output:**

> Result should be-
>
> COL1, 1, a,b,c,d, 2,3,4,
>
> COL2, 1,2,3,4,
>
> COL3,1,2,3,4,
>
> COL4, 1,2,3,4

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Comment: result should be-  COL1, 1, a,b,c,d, 2,3,4, COL2, 1,2,3,4,COL3, 1,2,3,4,COL4, 1,2,3,4,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this block of foreach:**

```
foreach ($menu as $col => $value) {
    echo '<hr>'.$col;
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $item => $subitem) {            
            if(is_array($subitem)){
                echo '<br>'.$item;
                foreach ($subitem as $childitem) {
                    echo '<br>'.$childitem;
                }
            }else{
                echo '<br>'.$subitem;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Menu Array**

```
Array
(
    [COL1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                    [3] => d
                )

            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )

    [COL2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [COL3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [COL4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

**Result**

```
COL1
1
a
b
c
d
2
3
4

COL2
1
2
3
4

COL3
1
2
3
4

COL4
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: col2,col3 & col4 should have subs as 1,2,3,4 in each of them

Comment: @FastReply, now check

Answer (score 0):

The third level is not an array all times. May be your $menu array is having incorrect data. Of it is not so then you have to check in the second level that `$subitem` is a array or not.

```
foreach ($menu as $col => $value) {
    echo '<hr>'.$col;
        foreach ($value as $item => $subitem) {
            echo '<br>'.$item;
            if(is_array($subitem)){
                foreach ($subitem as $childitem) {
                    echo '<br>'.$childitem;
                }
            } else {
                echo '<br>'.$subitem;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: result should be- COL1, 1, a,b,c,d, 2,3,4, COL2, 1,2,3,4,COL3, 1,2,3,4,COL4, 1,2,3,4 -  "your code not producing this

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from the inner `foreach` loop for this array:

```
'COL1' => array('1' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), '2', '3', '4')
```

The first time the outer loop runs
`$col = 'COL1'` and `$value=array(...)`;

The first time the inner loop executes, `$item='1'` and `$subitem=array(..)`.

But the second time the inner loop runs, an associative array does not exist for the second index. It's just a value, so: `$item='2'` but there is no value for `$subitem`

Comment: so what should be the code like - result should be- COL1, 1, a,b,c,d, 2,3,4, COL2, 1,2,3,4,COL3, 1,2,3,4,COL4, 1,2,3,4